Query overpass for expressway coverage by country
How can I write an query to list all countries and territories [admin_level=2] that drive on the right side, with their official English names, areas, total expressway lengths [highway=motorway] and sort descendingly by ratios of expressway lengths over corresponding areas?

How do you calculate the length of a motorway ? Because generally OSM indicate two different lines for each direction of a motorway. Also overpass is designed to extract data from OSM, if you then have to calculate something you should use another tool.

@obchardon Well I count lines individually so that is not a problem. I only need to divide the total length by area of each country to get these ratios
